# complex thinking on simple java challenge, how can i fix it?

Tags: java

Simple stuff but somehow not able to crack it, below piece of code gives compile time exception like `unexpected token` at `try/catch` and `unhandled exception:java.io.FileNotFound`

```
 String fileName = "C:\\GS.xlsx";
 try{
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(fileName));
 }catch(Exception e){

 }
```

What is the possible issue in here, i know there is something really goofy that am doing in here...

**Update**

Issue was, I didn't had my code in method...result of longs hrs of continous work...

```
 public class PositionGS {

    public PositionGS() {
        String fileName = "C:\\GS.xlsx";
        try {
            CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

that's the complete code...

Comment: Where is the file? Is the path correct?

Comment: @Scorpion: Yes, path is correct, file is in `C` drive...

Comment: Are you sure `Exception` here refers to `java.lang.Exception`, and not some other class?

Comment: That's not enough context.  Are you sure the compiler errors point to that specific line?  What's before and after the code you show.  Is it inside a method, or just inside a class declaration (which would cause that error)?

Comment: @nwinkler: It does not compile and so  do not have stacktrace...

Comment: It sounds like the exception is happening at compile time.  Can we get the code for the whole method?

Comment: Also, there's no such thing as "throwing unexpected token" -- that's a compiler message.

Comment: Not the cause here, but I don't think the CSVReader class will be able to read an actual Excel (.xlsx) file (as opposed to an Excel that you've save as CSV).

Comment: @LouisWasserman: Added complete code...

Comment: Is it possible that the file is locked from opening by, say, Excel? And are you sure the file exists. You didn't misspell anything did you?

Comment: @Rachel in Java when people say that something is *throwing XYZ* they are referring to an exception that has been thrown when the code runs. `unexpected token` and `unhandled exception` are compiler errors so you might want to reword the question slightly to avoid confusion. And post the code of the full method to provide more context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have this code inside a method or constructor, not sitting on its own in the class.

Comment: my bad, this is the issue if you spend 15 hrs at stretch on something...crazy really crazy...

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure this is the complete code? Your code is written right inside the class body and not inside any method or function!!